# DynamoDB getItem call not giving a response

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to read a basic DynamoDB table in AWS Lambda, following the AWS tutorials.  I've got some basic code, that seems to be running OK (I'm not seeing any errors logged), but I can't get any output:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-west-1'});
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

function readData(){

console.log("In the readData() function");

var params = {
    TableName: "desks",
    Key: {
        "desk_id": {N:'1'}
    }
};
console.log("Set params");
// Call DynamoDB to read the item from the table
ddb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
    console.log("In getItem callback function");
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Success", data.Item);
    }
});
console.log("Completed call");
}
```

When my function above is called, the logs show the output "Set params" and "Completed call", but it's like the callback function doesn't get executed.  Am I missing something around the execution flow?

Edit: I'm using Node.js 8.10 and I believe I've set up the appropriate role permissions (full access on the database).

Comment: Which node version? have you attached relevant role to lambda to get key from DyanmoDB?

Comment: Your "Completed call" log actually happens while the `ddb.getItem` call is still running. You need to look into and understand how asynchronous calls work in NodeJS. What else is in the logs after this? Does the function eventually time out? Or does it throw log error of some type? Also, have you configured the Lambda function to run inside a VPC?

Comment: Have updated with node version and roles - believe those are fine.  I'm relatively new to AWS, but haven't been trying anything clever with VPCs at all.  I just created the function and corresponding dynamoDB.  I get how the asynchronous calls work (ish), but there's literally nothing else in the logs - no errors, no timeout, no nothing.

Comment: Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is hook this up to an API trigger (I've got that bit working) and return the output of the query.  I suspect the issue is to do with asynchronous calls - is there a way to get the process to wait for a response form DynamoDB?  Could the lambda function have executed and shut down before the DB response was returned and the function no longer existed by the point the query executed?

Comment: Hi David, Did you try my solution? please let me know if i can assist.

Comment: I did - but I couldn't get it to work either.  I think I have a callback issue.  I'm still playing with it and will update as soon as I get somewhere, or have more information.  Might be 24 hours, but I haven't forgotten you!

Comment: Got it working - will post an update with the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out, Instead of working with specific API version, you can work with the [DocumentClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#get-property).

About AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient :

> The document client simplifies working with items in Amazon DynamoDB
> by abstracting away the notion of attribute values. This abstraction
> annotates native JavaScript types supplied as input parameters, as
> well as converts annotated response data to native JavaScript types.

About the get Function:

> Returns a set of attributes for the item with the given primary key by
> delegating to AWS.DynamoDB.getItem().

Code snippet:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
   region : 'REGION' 
});


function getItem(){

const params = {
  TableName : 'TABLE-NAME',
  Key: {
    'PRIMARY-KEY':'PRIMARY-KEY-VALUE'
  }
};
    
  db.get(params, (err, data) => {
  if (err){
    console.log("Error:", err);
  } 
  else{
    console.log("Success:", data.Item);
    
  } 
  console.log("Completed call");
});

}

exports.handler = (event) => {
    
 getItem()
 
};
```

By the way, you can use the Scan operation from DynamoDB UI,The scan operation returns one or more items that match the filter you specified.

[image]

I used it just to make sure the variables I entered are correct before hitting the lambda function.

Comment: Marked as the accepted answer, since it does actually work, however it turned out that a large part of the issue was around my mismanaging callbacks.  Once I introduced promises on my method calls, the above code worked.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same bug as you, and as you said in your comment, I was able to fix it by using a promise instead of the callback.

In my case, I was calling getItem two times, with the same object (or at least, objects that would stringify to be identical). The first call would succeed (the callback would be called), but the second call would not (the callback would never be called, and my code would hang). I don't know whether this has to do with caching, or what.

By the way, I noticed that you were not calling the handler's `callback` function, which might have been another issue.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-west-1'});
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

function readData(done){

  console.log("In the readData() function");

  var params = {
    TableName: "desks",
    Key: {
        "desk_id": {N:'1'}
    }
  };
  console.log("Set params");
  // Call DynamoDB to read the item from the table
  ddb.getItem(params).promise()
    .then((data) => console.log("Success", data.Item))
    .catch((err) => console.log("Error", err))
    .finally(done);

  // There's no equivalent for this, so I left it out.
  // console.log("In getItem callback function");

  console.log("Completed call");

}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    
  readData(callback);
 
};
```