# DynamoDB Get query passing two variable in Key

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to the world of AWS and currently working on Lambda function and DynamoDB.

What I am trying to do is we have a table called **Courses** and the primary key is "_id". We want to fetch all records where our `deleted_flag = false`.

```
let table = "Courses";
let flag = false; 
let params = {
            TableName: table,
            Key: {
                deleted_flag : flag
            } 
let course_list = await docClient.get(params).promise();
```

and I am getting this error

**err:  { ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema**

I am aware that "deleted_flag" is not the primary key but I don't know how to fetch data on this field.. ??

Also if I want to pass two values like `Key = {deleted_flag: false, name = "abc"}`, then how do I do that ?

Comment: Take a look at my answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58156179/dynamodb-getitem-call-not-giving-a- response/58158967#58158967

Comment: hey Amit, I am already using docClient.. you can see that in last line of my code. but thanks :)

Comment: I know, but I published a working piece of code you can use.

Comment: no sir, I am asking how to pass two values in Key = { } and fetch output. and also they are not a primary key. I am not sure how your answer can help me

Comment: You need to use the KeyConditionExpression and use the query() instead of get().

Comment: okay, will do so. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're performing a dynamodb get, which must be passed a partition and an optional sort key. To perform your query you'd need to do a scan with a filter expression.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html

This however will get very slow as your table grows as it's not a query dynamodb is optimised for.

Comment: then what is the ideal way of doing this? I am just starting so I can change to it now. as I said I have one table and I have a few conditions. All records passing those condition should be returned.

Comment: Also it will be great help if you can write small example similar to my code.. the URL you provided is very hard to understand for me as I am writing my first function. Thanks

Comment: In order to query on an attribute, the attribute should be the partition key or the sort key of the table or of an index defined for that table.

Comment: It's hard to say an ideal way as it depends on a bunch of factors.

One solution could be to store another record with a partition key value of "deletedrecords" and can store an array of all the partition keys which are flagged deleted. 

If your goal is to delete records look at dynamodb TTL (time to live)

Here's the nodejs example of scan:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.Scan

If the main query of your data is not based on a highly unique key then consider an aws RDS instead of dynamo.