# Return values from AWS DynamoDB JavaScript SDK are undefined

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js

I am currently using the JavaScript AWS SDK for DynamoDB and I am trying to parse the data I get from a DynamoDB call, but it always returns undefined. It does print the result successfully, but trying to store that data in a variable is unsuccessful. Below is how I am attempting to do it.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });
const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: "2012-08-10" });

const promisify = foo =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    foo((error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });

const params2 = {
  TableName: "Users",
  Key: {
    userID: { S: "123456789" },
  },
};

const test = params => {
  dynamoDb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
    } else {
      console.log("Success", data.Item);
      return data.Item;
    }
  });
};

let user = test(params2);
console.log("User:", user);
```

I believe it has to do with getItem being asynchronous and I have researched how to implement a promise into this code, but I cannot get the correct syntax. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think what's going on is Lambda calls the function, but it's not going to wait for the call back, so it thinks it is done and exits. Can you share the full code?

Comment: @AmitBaranes Just added the full code.

Comment: Take a look at my answer here :https://stackoverflow.com/a/58158967/9931092

Comment: promises / async functions don't work like this, unless you use async / await. promises don't have a return value, you need to do whatever with the value in the promise callback

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you are not returning anything from your `test` function. So it is expected that you get undefined outside.

Try to do it like this:

```js
// used aws promise api https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html
function test(params) {
    return dynamoDb.getItem(params).promise();
}

test(params2).then(
    user => {
        console.log('User:', user);
    },
    error => {
        console.log('Error:', error);
    },
);
```

Some further read:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function