# How to scan the dynamodb table form the AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to scan the Dynamodb table form my following code, can anyone please guide me what is wrong here.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
  region: "eu-west-1",
  apiVersion: "2012-08-10"
});

exports.handler = async (event, callback) => {
   const params = {
    TableName: "job_Status"
  };
  
  dynamodb.scan(params, (err, data) => {
      
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      callback(err);
    } else {
      console.log(data);
      callback(null, data);
      
    }
  });
};
```

I have given full dynamodb access role to the function but still it gives me the null response. Any idea what can be wrong here?

Response:
[image]

I tried with dynaomClient which not working too.

```
    const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
   region : 'eu-west-1' 
});

exports.handler = async (event, callback) => {
   const params = {
    TableName: "job_Status"
  };
  
  db.scan(params, (err, data) => {
      
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      callback(err);
    } else {
      console.log(data);
      callback(null, data);
      
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58158967/9931092

Comment: I have tried it, does not work too

Answer (score 1):

Your Lambda function is async but your code uses callbacks. By the time the callback is reached, your function has already been terminated because it ran asynchronously.  I'd speculate that the `null` output you see is the return value from the Lambda function, not your `console.log`.

Replace your call to scan with the following:

```
try{
  let results = await db.scan(params).promise()
  console.log(results);
} catch(err){
  console.log(err)
}
```

For more info, check out the AWS documentation about [working with promises](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html).